# Speech recognition for Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a robotics project that requires speech recognition. I want the finished product to be portable, so it will almost certainly use a Raspberry Pi. Is there any speech recognition software (or a speech recognition library) that runs efficiently on a Pi?

Requirements:

- Is for the English language.
- Runs efficiently on a Pi.
- Is...

  - ...able to be modified at the source code level (to run the robot), or
  - ...a library, so I can make my own program.
- Is free or inexpensive.
- Does not require internet access.

Comment: Related question on RPi.SE: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10384/speech-processing-on-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: What about the RPi.SE link you posted doesn't give you a good idea of what library you want?

Comment: @aman207 Nothing, I didn't see that question until two minutes ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a developer of [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net), an open source speech recognition toolkit. The main features of CMUSphinx for robot control and Raspberry Pi are:

- Accurate models are available for US English
- Good models are available for French, German and Spanish
- Any language can be supported
- Efficient decoding on low-resource hardware
- Noise-robust speech recognition
- Continuous listening mode with keyword activation
- Support for various languages like Python or Ruby

You can learn more about CMUSphinx from the [wiki](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki). If you have questions about CMUSphinx, feel free to ask on forums.

Comment: Do you have any feedback to provide about your experience of using CMUSphinx?

Comment: @Fractaliste, As the developer I can guarantee you that CMUSphinx can exceed your needs on speech recognition. If you have some specific question, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, could you contribute an answer to this question? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17124/building-speech-recognition-for-a-new-language-from-scratch/17126#17126